# Dropcam API: nexusapi.dropcam.com/get_image doesn't work anymore?

Tags: image, api, get, camera

For a year, if you make your dropcam public, you can use this code to get a dropcam snapshot:

```
<img src="https://nexusapi.dropcam.com/get_image?XXXXXXXXX>
```

Now, it doesn't work and it return this error message:

```
The query parameter 'uuid' was malformed: XXXXX is not valid camera uuid
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The uuid is specific to every camera.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to specify uuid as a parameter, for example https://nexusapi.dropcam.com/get_image?uuid=6a3cf1e5b10247a28d65bbdf49e1e6b8